# Decide if number is negative (in URM machine like language)

Tags: ds.algorithms, machine-models

So I'm learning to program in an assembly language for an abstract machine wich is very similar to an [URM Machine](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aUnlimited_Register_Machine).
An URM machine has 3 basic instructions (or 4 in some literature):
        To zero a register: Z(r)
        To increment a register: S(r)
        To Jump to a line or label if registers r1 and r2 contain the same value: J(r1,r2,l)
Now, my abstract machine is even weaker because, for jumping it only alows a comparison between a register and the literal 0.
To compensate it allows to assign any value to a register (not just zero as in the URM) and basic arithmetic operations.
Both machines allow an infinite number of registers.

I was able to write a program that successfully compares two positive numbers and returns the maximum.
Now I would like to make my program able to receive also negative numbers.

My question: How can I check if a number is negative? Is it even possible with only these instructions?

I confess that I'm not very clever with this kind of low level languages...

My maximum program follows: (input goes on r1 and r2 and output comes on r3)

```
maximo(){
    r5 := r1 - r3    
    jump (r5,0,maxr2)

    r5 := r2 - r4
    jump (r5,0,maxr1)


    r3 := r3 + 1
    r4 := r4 + 1
    jump (r1,r1,maximo)
}

maxr1(){
    r3 := r1 
}

maxr2(){
    r3 := r2 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: By the way, if you can subtract, you can reduce a comparison $a = b$ to a subtraction $x \gets a - b$ and comparison $x = 0$. Hence it should be obvious that your machine can easily do anything that a URM can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialise $x \gets v$ and $y \gets -v$. Then increment both $x$ and $y$ in parallel until one of them is equal to 0.